# dynamic manipulation via dictionary keys

Tags: python, pointers, dictionary, reference

I need to manipulate dynamic a dictionary on python. I have unrecognized information from input information, as in this example:

```
   'properties[props][defaultValue]': ''
   'properties[props][dt_precision]': ''
   'properties[props][dt_table]': ''
   'properties[props][dtfield]': ''
```

I need to convert to a dictionary like this example:

```
properties['props']['dt_table'] = 1
properties['props']['dt_table'] = 2
```

I don't know the real information, but I know that the format is like this:

```
variable[index] = value 
variable[index][index_1] = value
variable[index][index_1] [index_2]= value
variable[index][index_1] [index_2][index_3]= value
```

My problem is, how can I add a dictionary with infinite layers of keys? In others words, add a large hierarchy of subkeys to subkeys dynamically.

In javascript I use references like this:

```
f=var['key'];
f['key'] = {};
f = f['key'];
f['key'] = 120;
```

Which allows me to construct:

```
var['key']['key'] = 120
```

but the equivalent in python does not work.

Comment: It's possible to implement [Autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification#Python) in Python,

Answer (score 2):

**Naive approach**

The simplest approach, involves creating new dictionary on each sub-level by hand:

```
var = {}
var['key'] = {}
var['key']['key'] = 120

print(var['key']['key'])
print(var)
```

Which gives following output:

```
120
{'key': {'key': 120}}
```

**Autovivification**

You can automate it by using [`defaultdict`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification#Python) as suggested by @martineau in comments:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def tree():
    return defaultdict(tree)

v2 = tree()
v2['key']['key'] = 120

print(v2['key']['key'])
print(v2)
```

With output:

```
120
defaultdict(<function tree at 0x1ae7d88>, {'key': defaultdict(<function tree at 0x1ae7d88>, {'key': 120})})
```